# Enable Custom Module Store Specifically Magento 2 not working

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am trying to enable my custom module only for a single store view but the functionality is still working for all store views.

I have the following configuration:
Main Website > (Default store view, B2B Store view)
I want to enable my module only for the B2B Store view.

I tried to did this using system.xml: Code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
   <tab id="customrfq" translate="label" sortOrder="1000">
       <label>Request For Quote</label>
   </tab>
   <section id="customrfq" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
       <label>RFQ</label>
       <tab>customrfq</tab>
       <resource>CustomB2BRFQ_Module::rfq</resource>
       <group id="department" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
           <label>RFQ configuration</label>
           <field id="view_list" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
               <label>Show Quotes</label>
               <comment>Show request for quotes</comment>
               <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
           </field>
       </group>
   </section>
</system>
</config>
```

Config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
   <customrfq>
       <department>
           <view_list>1</view_list>
       </department>
   </customrfq>
</default>
</config>
```

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="CustomB2BRFQ\Module\Block\RequestForQuoteForm" name="custom_module_form"
                   template="CustomB2BRFQ_Module::rfq.phtml" ifconifg="customrfq/department/view_list" cacheable="false"/>
            <arguments>
               <argument name="path" xsi:type="helper" helper="CustomB2BRFQ\Module\Helper\Data::getPath" translate="true" />
            </arguments>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Helper File:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created By : Rashi Goyal
 */
namespace CustomB2BRFQ\Module\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    const PATH_FIELD = 'customrfq/department/view_list';
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context              $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ){
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::PATH_FIELD,\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }
}
```

Please specify what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set wrong values for following properties (system.xml):

- showInDefault
- showInWebsite
- showInStore

According to your requirement, you want functionality by store. So you have to set these properties like this:

- showInDefault="0"
- showInWebsite="0"
- showInStore="1"

Using this, your configuration setting display only on store view.

Also You have assigned default value = 1 (config.xml)

You should use by default this:
`<view_list>0</view_list>`